# New-Item not working if use C# to call Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The original question is quite big, and now I narrow down to:

The following powershsell script works if I run it in powershell console window, and $appPool is Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement type, and a new application pool can be created in my IIS.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$appPool = New-Item ("IIS:\AppPools\$iissitename")
```

However if I use C# to run my script, the $appPool will be NULL, and no application pool is created.

Any idea? Thanks heaps!

--------- **Update** ------------

If I use other Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets like:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-Website
```

My C# project will throw the exception like: Cannot find a provider with the name 'WebAdministration'

------ **Update More** ------

Some other powershell command like "Get-ChildItem IIS:\apppools" all not working when calling from C#.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `WebAdministration` module is 64-bit only - at least on the 64-bit system I tested on.  Either that or some of the COM components it depends on haven't been registered in the 32-bit registry hive.  Make sure to compile your C# app as x64.

Comment: Hi Keith, I did, and it's the same.

Comment: It is interesting that if I fire up an x86 PowerShell prompt, I can import webadministration with no errors.  But if I try to GCI IIS:\ I get the error: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to
the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`.  It seems like some required COM server isn't registered in the 32-bit hive.

Comment: For the error you mention here, maybe could use regsvr32 xxx. dll

Comment: Also to register COM dll in Powershell, if running console in normal mode, must have "-Verb runAs"

Comment: When I need to use WebAdministration, I just use it from a 64-bit prompt and have no problems.  And since our admin disables UAC I'm running as admin, so again no problems due to lack of privileges.  :-)

Comment: Hi Keith, I got the same "COM not register" error when build as 'Any CPU'. If changing to X64, it's OK. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keith, problem comes again! I have 2 components which need project build in both x86 and x64 :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556220/how-about-net-project-needs-to-build-under-both-x64-and-x86

Comment: You can test process bit size using either IntPtr.Size or System.Environment.Is64BitProcess, if the process is 64-bit then your good to go.  If you find you're running in a 32-bit process do your webadmin work like so `Invoke-Command localhost { ipmo webadministration; get-website; ...}`.  That will run this script against a 64-bit PowerShell remoting endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might find the answer. It seems IIS related command in Powershell needs administrator right to run. If I use C# to call the ps file, the command in ps should like:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-WebSite }"
```